# You'll be among aces (5-letter word)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> Used as a noun, 
>   It can take you to places 
>   Followed as a verb, 
>   You'll be among aces

What is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is

> TRAIN

*Used as a noun,
It can take you to places*

> Using a train you can travel to different places.

*Followed as a verb,
You'll be among aces*

> By training, you can become an ace (i. e. an expert) in a discipline, activity...

Comment: Nicely done, Edivad!